# Jenkins doesn't use resolved maven's dependencies in Post-build Actions

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I have a Maven job. In `Build`, for example, I use `mvn compile` with my `settings.xml`.

This `settings.xml` contains credentials to our Nexus Repository which stores some internal dependencies.

The problem is that when build will execute `Post-build Actions` (Post build task - Shell) with the same maven goal `mvn compile` it fails. It depends on build **tries to download all dependencies and plugins again** (but now it's without .

My question: How to share dependencies from `Build` step to step `Post-build Actions`

---

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to compile twice?

Comment: @Atxulo It's just an example. Instead of `compile` can be any other goal

Comment: First I would ask why do you use a post build action to call `compile` ? The build will run in the primary part ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'll try explain with abstract example. Imagine you run some code via Build and your build was aborted and you want to do something like send information about abort to database.

For this case I use the same repository and have two objects with scripts: `Main` and `BuildWasAborted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution!

At first you need to know the path to your maven local repository and pass it into maven cli via param `maven.repo.local`:

```bash
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/maven-repositories/0 compile
```

And then the most important thing. For avoid download dependencies again you have to delete `*.sha1` and `*.repositories` from your local maven repository. I don't why... but it how works Maven...

It's an example of full script:

```bash
find /home/jenkins/maven-repositories/0 -type f \( -iname "*.repositories" -o -iname "*.sha1" \) -exec rm -f {} \;

mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/maven-repositories/0 compile
```

Answer (score 0):

One configuration that can cause this, is if you have selected "Use private Maven repository" under the Advanced settings of the Build step:
[image: Showing the advanced settings of the Maven build step]

The build step then makes use of this private repository and downloads all dependencies in there.

Your post action executes Maven from the command line without all the extra configuration of the Jenkins Maven jobtype. So it uses the default Maven repository instead of the private one, and hence has to download all your dependencies again.

One solution can then be to figure out where the repository is (e.g. in your workspace as `.repository/`) and pass that to your Post-action Maven with `mvn compile -Dmaven.repo.local=.repository`.

A better solution is to NOT use the Maven job type, but a Freestyle job instead, as recommended in [one of the 40 Jenkins tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dYM0XUrXHc&t=657s). The Maven Job type provides convenience, but also hides the complexity and that is exactly what is causing these issues, so consider switching.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. And advice about Freestyle job type instead of Maven it's a really good point. Thanks!

Comment: In the same time, it doesn't work :( 

Fortunately I found the way how to resolve this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75521594/7512201